# regex with replaceAll

Tags: java

I have done some searching and would like advice on this problem:

I want to replace `"labels":"Webapp"` with `"labels":["Webapp"]`

I found the regex `(\"labels\"\:\")+(([a-zA-Z]|\s|\-)+)+(\")` with the following substitution `"labels":["$2"]`

I use the method replaceAll and the Talend editor.

I write `output_row.json = output_row.json.replaceAll("(\"labels\"\:\")+(([a-zA-Z]|\s|\-)+)+(\")",""labels":["$2"]");` but It doesn't work.

> Message détaillé: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ )

Then I escaped the characters, I did:

```
output_row.json = output_row.json.replaceAll("(\\"labels\\"\:\\")+(([a-zA-Z]|\\s|\-)+)+(\\")","\"labels\":[\"$2\"]");
```

But It doesn't work yet.

Please could you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues : don't escape `-` and `:` they are not special characters in `regex`

escape `\s` with `\\s` plus escape `"` as you did in your second example `\"labels\":[\"$2\"]`

Although you can use a more concise regex and combine your `\\s` , `-` inside [`character class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) `[]`

You can use [`(\"labels\":\")+([a-zA-Z -]+)\`](https://regex101.com/r/eF8MLb/1)

```
System.out.println("labels\":\"Webapp"
        .replaceAll("(\"labels\":\")+([a-zA-Z -]+)\""
                , "\"labels\":[\"$2\"]"));
```